# why I could not be able to visible a specific part after hover?

Tags: html, css, menu, hover, dropdown

I made a simple dropdown menu.When I hover "Social Media" section ,I want to show some social icon like a dropdown menu.I made those social media icon part hidden . And I want to make it visible only during to hover on "social media" part.But it is not working.The icon part is not shown after hover.Please help me out.I couldn't not be able to find my problem.

**Html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Menu</title>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./menu.css">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css">
    
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    
        <div class="social">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Social Media</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-menu{
    background: black;
}
.main-menu ul {
    text-align: center;
}
.main-menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.main-menu ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px 56px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-left:1px rgb(70, 67, 67) solid;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.main-menu ul li :last-child{
    border-right:1px rgb(70, 67, 67) solid;
}

.main-menu ul li:hover>a{
    background-color: rgb(70, 67, 67);
    transition: .5s;
}

/* dropdown menu*/

.main-menu ul li ul{
    position: absolute;
    left: -4px;
    top:100%;
    width: 300px;
    background: black;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaley(0);
    transform-origin: top;

}

.main-menu ul li ul li{
    display: block;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.main-menu ul li ul li a{
    display: block;
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(70, 67, 67);
}

.main-menu ul li ul li:last-child{
    border-right: none;
}

/* hover style */

.main-menu ul li:hover ul{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .5s;
    transform: scaley(1);

}

/* social media */

.social{
    text-align: center;   
    margin-top: 50px; 
}
.social ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.social ul li{
    height: 42px;
    width:225px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 35px;
    position: relative;
}
.social ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
}
.social ul li:hover{
    background-color: rgb(114, 114, 114);
    transition: .5s;
}

/* dropdown */


.social ul li ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 140%;   
    left: -145px;
    width: 500px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.social ul li ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 22px;
}
.social ul li ul li a{
    font-size: 45px;
    color: white;
    padding:0px;
}


/* hover */
.social ul li :hover .social ul li ul{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. You were using hover part as `.social ul li:hover .social ul li ul`  whereas it should be like `.social:hover ul li ul`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-menu {
  background: black;
}

.main-menu ul {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.main-menu ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 56px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-left: 1px rgb(70, 67, 67) solid;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.main-menu ul li :last-child {
  border-right: 1px rgb(70, 67, 67) solid;
}

.main-menu ul li:hover>a {
  background-color: rgb(70, 67, 67);
  transition: .5s;
}


/* dropdown menu*/

.main-menu ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -4px;
  top: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scaley(0);
  transform-origin: top;
}

.main-menu ul li ul li {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.main-menu ul li ul li a {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(70, 67, 67);
}

.main-menu ul li ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}


/* hover style */

.main-menu ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .5s;
  transform: scaley(1);
}


/* social media */

.social {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.social ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.social ul li {
  height: 42px;
  width: 225px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 35px;
  position: relative;
}

.social ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.social ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(114, 114, 114);
  transition: .5s;
}


/* dropdown */

.social ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140%;
  left: -145px;
  width: 500px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.social ul li ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 22px;
}

.social ul li ul li a {
  font-size: 45px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
}


/* hover */

.social:hover ul li ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="social">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Social Media</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4bnupdL8/)

Answer (score 0):

Change you last css selector with this

```
/* hover */
.social:hover ul li ul{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Although you will now run into the problem that you cant click the icons since they have `position: absolute;` if you try to hover over them the hover on `.social` will get removed